# How do I make editor display be same as editor constrained area? (Xcode IOS)

Tags: ios, xcode

currently when I am adding constraints to my views - the new "constrained" area shows up in orange - but my original views (at least in the editor) stay exactly where they are.

How do I make them go to the orange spot in the editor without having to manually move them each time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look to following screenshot:

[image: To place object on orange space]

Comment: When I run without pressing that button. It still appears normal in the simulator. What is the point of showing it in the wrong location in the editor? Why is this even a feature?

Comment: May be this link will help you ... 
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html